# Постпозитивный номинатив в начале абзаца

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, оформление-текста, абзац

> Вы в курсе про самый странный трансфер лета. Алексей Сутормин 28 июня еще был игроком «Оренбурга», на следующий день оказался в «Рубине», а сегодня был представлен как игрок «Зенита». Говорят, не обошлось без звонка Алексея Миллера.

> **Максимально странная история**. Радует, что в специфической ситуации оба клуба не отделались сухими анонсами, а решили в самоиронию.

**Максимально странная история** — это постпозитивный номинатив? Может ли начинаться новый абзац с постпозитивного номинатива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вступление (моё общее понимание темы)**

**1. Теория**

Теория номинативных конструкций разработана еще недостаточно, поэтому ориентироваться в этой теме сложно. Если всё-таки есть такая необходимость, то, как мне кажется, **начинать надо с четких определений.**

Номинативная (назывная) конструкция в классическом варианте   — **это сущ. в И.п. (наименование предмета),** которое может иметь при себе определение (согласованное или несогласованное).

Морфологически одинаковые словосочетания тем не менее различаются по семантике и функциям, поэтому среди них можно выделить **4 вида:** (1) номинативное предложение,  (2) номинатив в препозиции (именительный темы),  (3) двусоставное предложение с инверсией и (4) постпозитивный номинатив.

Варианты 1 и 2 действительно являются **номинативными** (назывными) – это восприятие предмета в момент речи, а варианты 3 и 4 имеют **оценочное** значение.

**2. Примеры**

2.1. ***ХорОший актер!  КлАссное видео! КрасИвый пейзаж!***

Наблюдатель видит предмет, но он не дает ему собственного названия (оно уже есть), а оценивает только качество. Хороший, классное, красивый  – это сказуемые в двусоставных предложениях с инверсией.

2.2. ***Видел я на днях «Крокодиловы слёзы» — бездарнейшая пятиактная белиберда***.  Или: ***Ну и пьеса! Какое убожество!***

Это постпозитивный номинатив, в это случае все словосочетание (сущ. + прилаг.) имеет оценочное значение и выражает мнение автора. Постпозитивный номинатив  (ПН) может обособляться тире или оформляться как отдельное предложение.

В то же время ПН всегда следует после какого-либо текста, **прилагается к нему.**

2.3. **А если текста нет, а сразу обозначается впечатление**, например:

***Какое убожество! У неё только две ножки!***
Тогда это скорее номинативное предложение с оценочным значением, разновидность варианта 1.

**Ответ на вопрос**

Если  фразу «Максимально странная история» разместить **конце первого абзаца**,  то это **постпозитивный номинатив** (всё словосочетание является оценкой).

Если фраза находится **в начале** следующего абзаца, то это реакция на ранее прочитанный текст, и формально сочетание следует считать **номинативным предложением со значением оценки.**

Comment: Большое спасибо! А если это будет начало абзаца и дополнительно будет использоваться вводное слово "Словом, максимально странная история.", то здесь тоже сочетание следует считать номинативным предложением со значением оценки?

Comment: Я думаю, что "словом, максимально странная история" с оценочным значением может стоять только в конце абзаца, тогда это можно считать постпозитивным номинативом. А в начале абзаца это уже не оценка, а скорее рассуждение такого вида: "Если подытожить сказанное ранее, то все это выглядит как странная история". Номинативное оценочное предложение - это, как мне кажется,  непосредственная РЕАКЦИЯ на  сказанное или услышанное.